# Android Save Encryption Keys

Tags: android, performance, encryption

What is the most efficient way to save RSA Private and Public Key or symmetric key in android. I am using [Keystore api](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). Is there a  better solution for 2016 to save encryption keys??

Answer (score 1):

Taking a leaf out of the [Android Security Cookbook](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Android-Security-Cookbook-Keith-Makan-ebook/dp/B00HL2GODC)

> The API for the `KeyChain` class was also updated in Android 4.3 to allow developers to determine whether the device supports hardware-backed certificate store or not. This basically means that the device supports a secure element for the certification store. This is an exciting enhancement as it promises to keep the certificate store safe even on **rooted devices**. However, not all devices support this hardware feature.

**Relevant Resources**

[Keystore redesign in Android M](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/keystore-redesign-in-android-m.html)

[ARM TrustZone Technology](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/index.php)

Comment: whats your opinion about  <a href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref "> SharedPreferences</a>?

Comment: Depends on what concerns you have. Essentially `SharedPreferences` are private to your app by default.